# Symfony complex environment configuration

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

Assume (simplified) I have a stage machine and a live machine. Both should be tested using the prod environment. Unfortunately on our stage machine there is one memcache instance available. On live there are three memcache instances. We have to use the Memcache extension. To configure it on live we're using a configuration like:

```
services:
  memcache.servers:
    class: Memcache
    calls:
      - [ addserver, ["one.mc.live", %memcache.server.port% ] ]
      - [ addserver, ["two.mc.live", %memcache.server.port% ] ]
      - [ addserver, ["three.mc.live", %memcache.server.port% ] ]

  common_cache:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache
    calls:
        - [ setNamespace, [%memcache.namespace%] ] #from parameters.yml
        - [ setMemcache, [@memcache.servers] ]
```

Additionally on live we're adding slaves to our doctrine connection, on staging we don't. On live we want to send logs to a remote service, on stage we don't (but every other logger should be configured the same way!). On stage URLs should be accessible without any "app_stage.php" prefixes. Obviously this needs a little more (complex) machine specific configuration than we could solve using parameters.yml.

To get this kind of machine-specific configuration working I first used a config_local.yml (unversioned) that is imported by config_prod.yml first and config_prod.yml adds what is needed for running prod. This attempt fails when it comes to logging since Monolog won't "forget" a logger chain that has been defined once (you cannot simply "override" a main: logger, the old one will still be there and produce duplicated logs).

So I currently try to go a different way: I removed config_prod.yml from version control and added a (versioned) config_stage.yml that has basic prod configuration but doesn't define any loggers for example. The locally modified config_prod.yml imports it and adds configuration details for the environment.

I don't feel good with not having config_prod.yml under git since we cannot trace configuration changes. We have to tell our designers how to create their own config_prod.yml for local testing. We have to create a config_prod (+ parameters.yml) on every live instance.

Is this a  way to do things or have I just missed something in the Symfony2 configuration docs?